# How to split a field that has carriage return

Tags: t-sql

I have a field in my database table called ADDRESSFORMAT

1,The Lodge

Street

Town

Postcode

Where the contents are separated by a CHAR (13) and CHAR (10)

How would I go about creating fields in a query that would only pull back either the first line, second line...and so on?

Comment: Please: (1) format your question properly, (ii) provide both sample data and results, (C) specify the database software, and (4) show your code and research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an in-line approach.

The Cross Apply B generates a "clean string".  It will eliminate any number of repeating CRLFs and create a pipe delimited string to be processed by Cross Appy C.

I should note that this method of eliminating repeating strings was demonstrated by **Gordon Linoff** several weeks back.  Sorry I can't find the original post.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,ADDRESSFORMAT varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'The Lodge

Street

Town

Postcode')

Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select CleanString = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(ADDRESSFORMAT,char(13),'|'),char(10),'|'),'|','><'),'<>',''),'><','|')
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(B.CleanString,'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 

             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1        Pos2    Pos3    Pos4        Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
1   The Lodge   Street  Town    Postcode    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```